# Add webservice created from Dynamic web project to a simple web project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, web

I have created a new dynamic web project in Eclipse
and then Created a bottom up Java webservice 
   ---> (Now we have webservice project and webservice client project)

I need to implement the webservice project methods directly in an old simple web project which was previously created. any help?

Comment: I dont understand what you need exaclty

Comment: I have a simple web project and from the other hand a webservice project created using eclipse dynamic web project ... I need to add the webservice project classes inside the simple web project taking into consideration the configuration files as wsdd.xml , web.xml  , ....

Comment: Let's say my first concern was to add a webservice inside my simple web app project ... instead of creating the webservice inside my webapp , I have created a new dynamic web project using eclipse from which i have generated webservice and webservice client ... now i want to copy the webservice classes and confirguration xml files into my first project

Comment: if you are using eclipse what about importing your webservice into your web app project?